# HP Laser 108a printer not detected via USB

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I have bought a budget printer HP laser 108a, and was using it very well on my Windows machine, but when I shifted to Ubuntu 21.04, I am not able to detect it in **Add Printer** settings, I downloaded its driver from [HP official website](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laser-100-printer-series/24494339/model/24494345) and installed it but there was no progress, I tried removing ippusbxd after looking to some articles but it wasn't there in my desktop, I installed HPLIP, but still found no progress. In **Add Printer** I only see **CUPS-BRF**, please provide a solution.
PS. It is a USB printer.

Edit 1: I have used hp-setup and hp-setup --gui, but it cannot detect my printer. It says no device attached

Edit 2: Yes even I read it that its rebadged from some Samsung printer, and for **lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7** I got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqSKE.png)

Comment: Please give what you get for `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`.

Comment: The Laser 108a is probably a rebadged Samsung. It is not supported by HPLIP, so it is pointless using that software. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPrintQueues#hpuld.

Comment: @brian_p I have made edits to my question, and please tell me what can I use instead of HPLIP.

Comment: @user68186 Edits made to the question

Comment: There is little I can add that is not at the link I gave. You need uld-hp_V1.00.39.12_00.15.tar.gz.

Comment: @brian_p thanks man but I already tried that out, it didn't work either.